# Django timezone's now, what am I missing?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I'm having a hard time understanding how timezones works in django, so I looked at the source code in [django/utils/timezone.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/utils/timezone.py#L320) and I found the following code:

```
def now():
    """
    Returns an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ.
    """
    if settings.USE_TZ:
        # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
        return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    else:
        return datetime.now()
```

And I don't really understand why the provided tzinfo doesn't depend on settings.py's TIME_ZONE.

Shouldn't it be something like that instead?

```
return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=get_default_timezone())
```

This way timezone.now() will really be time zone aware, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) is enabled, Django stores all datetimes in UTC and uses the [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#time-zone) setting to display the stored timezone.

From the django's [timezone docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime
>   information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime
>   objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in
>   templates and forms.

Comment: "Django stores all datetimes in UTC". This is not precise. Django doesn;t always do that

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @MihaiZamfir. i've updated the answer.

Comment: From the source code, the UTC class seemed like a dummy "Return 0 offset", but I think I got it now, thanks !